# Class methods can't be used for andmap?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

While working on a Racket program for managing employee time sheets, I found that I cannot use a class's member method for `andmap`.

```
#lang racket

(define example%
  (class object%

    (super-new)

    (define/public (is-even? n)
      (even? n))

    (define/public (test)
      (println
       ;; Next line causes error.
       (andmap is-even? '(2 3 4))))))
       ;; if the following line is used, everything works properly
       ;;(andmap even? '(2 3 4))))))

(let ([tmp (new example%)])
  (send tmp test))
```

DrRacket gives the following error message on attempt to run this simple program:

> class: misuse of method (not in application) in: is-even?

---

Of course I don't **need** to use `andmap` ... It is just a luxury since I can feed a lambda and the result of `map` into `addmap` and get the same functionality...

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either, giving the same error as the previous program...

```
#lang racket

(define example%
  (class object%

    (super-new)

    (define/public (iseven? n)
      (even? n))

    (define/public (test)
      (println
       (let ([true? (lambda
                        (v)
                      (equal? v #t))])
         (andmap true?
                 ;; map also refuses to use my class's method...
                 ;; so much for my hacky workaround idea.
                 (map iseven? '(2 3 4))))))))

(let ([tmp (new example%)])
  (send tmp test))
```

I like to fix my own problems so I looked up the given error message. I didn't find anything related. This leads to the following question: Why can't `andmap`, `map`, etc. use a class's method for their procedure argument?

**PS:** The actual class is significantly more complicated, but this is a minimal, verifiable example. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Racket, a method is actually implemented by a macro that rewrites

```
(method arg ...)
```

to

```
(method-impl this arg ...)
```

where `method-impl` is bound either to the method implementation itself (if the method is private or final) or to some code that fetches the right method implementation from the class's vtable.

You can eta-expand the method name, like this:

```
(andmap (lambda (x) (is-even? x)) xs)
```

or you can use `for/and`:

```
(for/and ([x (in-list xs)]) (is-even? x))
```

You just have to use `is-even?` (or any other method name) in operator position.

As to why Racket's class library works that way: I'm not sure. It would be possible to make method names used as expressions (ie, not in operator position) do the `lambda` wrapping automatically; the current implementation deliberately doesn't do that, but I'm not sure what the rationale is.

Comment: That's a good point. It might be worth asking what the rational is for that, and if its worth changing.